# How to make recursive functions to execute one by one in node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have used recursive functions say f1(); f2(); f3(); etc and called one after another
and i want to make them run one by one, means until f1 doesn't get finished f2 or f3 shouldn't be called. I tried step but it not works for recursive functions.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272797/how-do-i-chain-on-another-callback-function-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the async utilities arround, for example this with [async series](https://github.com/caolan/async#control-flow-1)

```
var utile = require('utile');

utile.async.series([
  function(cb) {
    console.log('this is a');
    cb();
  },
  function(cb) {
    console.log('this is b');
    cb();
  }
]);
```